# OCaml variant types: confusing the compiler

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm trying to understand variants in OCaml (while this isn't homework, the assignment is taken from my friend's *old* assignment, so please don't give corrected code).

I have the following code, representing a family tree. The idea is that each family tree is either unknown, or a person; the person contains a link to other family_trees.

```
type family_tree = Unknown | Person of person 
  and person = {name: string; year_of_birth: int; 
                mother: family_tree; father: family_tree}
```

However, when I try to actually use the code to represent a family, I get the error

```
Error: This expression has type person but an expression was expected 
of type family_tree
```

Example of code that produces the error:

```
let ron: family_tree = {name = "Ron Smith"; year_of_birth = "1953";
                        mother = Unknown; father = Unknown}
let jim: family_tree = {name = "Jim Smith"; year_of_birth = "1983";
                        mother = Unknown; father = ron}
```

How can I prevent OCaml from thinking that ron is a `person`, instead of a `family_tree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `{name = "Ron Smith"}` is a `person` but you need a `family_tree` which is defined as `Person person`, and you need to specify the variant name together with it:

```
let ron: family_tree = Person {name = "Ron Smith"; ... }
```

Otherwise you wouldn't be able to distinguish a `family_tree` as `Person` from a `person`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, you need to write

    let ron: family_tree = Person {name = "Ron Smith"; ... }

to have the code compile in OCaml.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, fixed.